# How to strictly test objectContaining with jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Is there a way to strictly test `.objectConaining` with jest?

Basically the code below checks for one of they object keys, and the tests passes, but i don't want it to pass.

Is there some sort of way to test this object strictly, like `.toStrictEquals` so that the test will not only check for specific keys but for the object structure as well?

```js
it('should work', () => {
  const spy = jest.fn();
  const obj = {
    hello: "world",
    foo: "bar",
  }

  spy(obj);

  expect(spy).toBeCalledWith( expect.objectContaining({
    hello: expect.stringContaining("world")
  }));
});
```

Basically my goal is to check for `obj` **stricly**.

Comment: Is your goal to not allow keys other than `hello`?

Comment: Edited, Basically my goal is to check for obj stricly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by strictly.

Comment: You can look into Jest docs and see `toStrictEqual`

Comment: What test results do you want? Can you give more text cases too?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
it('should work', () => {
  const obj = {
    hello: "world",
    foo: "bar",
  }

  expect(obj).toEqual({
    hello: "world"
  })
});
```

Which will print the following:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

- Expected  - 0
+ Received  + 1

  Object {
+   "foo": "bar",
    "hello": "world",
  }

   5 |   }
   6 |
>  7 |   expect(obj).toEqual({
     |               ^
   8 |     hello: "world"
   9 |   })
  10 | });
```